# CRM 2011 deleting managed solution dependency issues

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I need to delete a managed solution from an organisation without losing the data or the fields inside... So obviously there are dependency issues. I added the same solution unmanaged with a different name, hoping that this would solve the dependency issues but when I try to delete the managed solution is still get a whole list.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fix this in a supported way (through GUI and/or organization service).

My first idea would be to try and remove the solution components from the managed solution first and finally remove the solution itself. There actually is a `RemoveSolutionComponentRequest`, but according to the SDK this request is only valid for unmanaged solutions.

If you need to remove particular dependencies, you could try the `DisassociateRequest` on the Dependency entity. I don't know if it will work in your scenario, but maybe it is worth to give it a try.

A last resort would be to remove the managed solution, along with its components and dependencies directly from the database. Be very cautious with this approach: it is unsupported and potentially you can end up with a system that does not allow you to import solutions at all.

Comment: Yeah, we decided to keep them. It might be to risky to try and delete them. Thanks for your input anyway.